# Problems using GStack->GetLocalAddressList(LList) in C++

Tags: c++builder, indy

I am trying to use the `GetLocalAddressList()` as referenced in
https://www.indyproject.org/2014/03/14/tidstack-addlocaladdressestolist-method-is-now-deprecated/

I have translated the Delphi code to C++

```
#include <IdStack.hpp>

TIdStackLocalAddressList* LList;
TIdStackLocalAddress* LAddr;
int idx;

try {
    LList = new TIdStackLocalAddressList();
    try {
        GStack->GetLocalAddressList(LList);
        for (idx = 0; idx < LList->Count - 1; idx++) {
            LAddr = LList->Addresses[idx];
            switch (LAddr->IPVersion) {
                case Id_IPv4:
                    // Add to list Items
                    ListBox1->Items->Add(LAddr->IPAddress);
                    break;
                case Id_IPv6:
                    break;
                default:;
            }
        }
    } catch (...) {
    }
} __finally
{
    delete LList;
}
```

I get

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class 0xc0000005 with message 'Exception 0xc0000005 encountered at address 0x408b38: Access violation reading location 0x00000000'.

When I execute `GStack->GetLocalAddressList(LList);`

I assume that it is because I haven't made a GStack object, but I have no reference as to how/when to do that. I have looked on the web an can't seem to find any good references for using Indy with Builder :(

Can someone help out? Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GStack` is a global singleton object that Indy uses to abstract access to platform-specific APIs.

If you have other Indy components alive at the time you run this code, the `GStack` object is already created for you.  But if there are no objects alive, you have to create the `GStack` object before you can use it.

Fortunately, the singleton is reference-counted - it is created when the 1st reference is added, and then destroyed when the last reference is removed. The `TIdStack` class has public `static` methods for managing this reference counting.  You should use those methods when using `GStack` directly, if you are not sure whether other Indy components are alive or not, eg:

```cpp
TIdStack::IncUsage(); // creates GStack if needed
try
{
    // now you can safely use GStack as needed...
}
__finally
{
    TIdStack::DecUsage();  // destroys GStack if needed
}
```

---

On a side note, your `for` loop should not be subtracting `1` from the `LList->Count` when using the `<` comparison. The loop should be:

```cpp
for (idx = 0; idx < LList->Count; idx++)
```

Comment: Works like a champ. Thanks again Remy

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Remy. Yes this is for stand-alone usage, to load a ComboBox for user selection of a Binding IP. With newer computers having multiple NIC, I needed a way for the user to select which network to use for talking to other applications.

For those looking for how to do this, Below is the modified code:

```
#include <IdStack.hpp>
// ----------------------------

TIdStackLocalAddressList* LList;
TIdStackLocalAddress* LAddr;
int idx;

try {
    LList = new TIdStackLocalAddressList();
    TIdStack::IncUsage(); // creates GStack if needed
    try {
        GStack->GetLocalAddressList(LList);
        for (idx = 0; idx < LList->Count; idx++) {
            LAddr = LList->Addresses[idx];
            switch (LAddr->IPVersion) {
                case Id_IPv4:
                    // Add to list Items
                    ListBox1->Items->Add(LAddr->IPAddress);
                    break;
                case Id_IPv6:
                    // Right Now I don't care about IPv6
                    break;
                default:;
            }
        }
    } catch (...) {
    }
} __finally
{
    TIdStack::DecUsage(); // destroys GStack if needed
    delete LList;
}
//
```

My App is using a second NIC for Audio-Over-IP (AOIP) and I didn't want the Apps using the same NIC as the Audio.